# Making the same website accessible from the subdirectory

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I want my same website to accessible from a subdirectory. For example, right now my website is

```
https://example.com
```

What I want is, that it should also be reachable using:

```
https://example.com/hi
```

That means each path that is accessible from `https://example.com` should also be accessible from `https://example.com/hi`. How could I do this. Here is what I tried in my server config.

```
    location /hi {
          proxy_pass https://example.com
    }
```

Right now, if I try `https://example.com/hi`, it gives out `Bad Gateway`. What is it that I should be doing?

Comment: You should be checking the error log.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `proxy_pass` did you try using `rewrite`?

```
location /hi/ {
 rewrite ^/hi(/.*)$ $1 break;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what has happened here?

Comment: The subdirectory `/hi/` gets rewritten so for the server it looks like `/` was requested. No need to `proxy_pass` since the website is not on a remote server. Otherwise just add it.